# USB flash drive showing up as two disks

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB flash drive, which when I insert into my mac's USB port, shows up as two disks. One has a capacity of 2.11 GB, and has read/write privileges, the other has 2.1 MB capacity and is read only. I tired reformatting the 2.11 GB disk using disk utility, and making it have one partition, but that did not solve the issue.

The flash drive is not new, and I think the previous user of it did this. The read only disk also contains a .pdf file. Is there any way I could make it to show up as one disk with read and write privileges? I would like to keep it formatted as FAT because I need to use it with my mac and a pc running windows xp.

Answer (score 1):

Some vendors (Sandisk comes to mind) make their flash drives appear to also be a CD-ROM, with "encryption" software or, in your case, some meaningless documentation.  In the Disk Utility try removing/re-creating the entire partition table, then re-creating the FAT system.  Some vendors make this even trickier where you need to visit their website and download a utility to remove this extra disk/partition and claim it as usable space in the main drive.

With the drive inserted, open a terminal screen and type `mount` *[enter]*  if you see the disks listed as something like `/dev/disk1s1` ... `/dev/disk2s1` (differing disk#) then its a hardware/firmware issue with the drive itself, pointing the possibility of a utility from the manufacturer to consolidate it.
If you see `/dev/disk1s1` ... `/dev/disk1s2` (same disk#, differing s#) then the partitioning answers should have worked.

What is your brand/model USB flash drive?

Comment: Im not sure what brand it is, because it doesn't have a brand name  on it. It has the logo of a company which was giving them out, but they don't make the flash drives themselves.

Comment: On your mac, go to [Apple] About this Mac, System/More Info, USB, and find the VendorID and ProductID of the USB drive in the list.  they are both 4-digit values (ABCD or 0xABCD)

Comment: when I open about this mac, and go to more info, I clicked on the "Storage" tab, and saw this: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/vtJwPgw.jpg) the top one is my internal hard drive, and the other two are from the flash drive. there was no USB section.

Comment: open a terminal window, with the drive plugged in type `mount`   What do you see?

Comment: /dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/*name of read only disk* (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/*name of read and write disk* (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)

Comment: So this shows it is indeed not a partition issue but the drive representing itself as 2 distinct pieces of hardware.  /dev/disk1s1 and /dev/disk2s1 vs /dev/disk1s1 and /dev/disk1s2.  If you can find the vendor ID we may be able to get you a utility from them to remove this.  You need to find the screen like on this page http://blog.unfed.org/2013/10/using-aten-uc-232a-usb-to-serial.html

Comment: I think I found the vendor ID... I found the flash drive in the "system information" app, and this is what came up: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QDWxlO1.jpg) @EriirkE

Answer (score -1):

Use **GParted** (I recommend it) or the Windows Disk Management Tool (right click on Computer → Manage... → Hard drives) to remove the extra partitions and resizing the first one to occupy the free space and your problem is solved.

Comment: -1 This is a firmware issue.

Comment: Are you completely shure? I've had about 3 or 4 sticks with that extra partition and creating a new partition table solved the issue. Also rounding to cylinder/MiB when creating a partition may leave some trailing free space.

Comment: The OP indicated that it shows as two separte drive, U3-style.

Comment: I don't know what _U3-style_ stands for but doesn't ejecting one drive would eject the other "drive" as well? If that is the case then it may just be, as I said, just another partition of the same device displayed as another drive (e.g. Thunar under my Fedora 20 box displays every partition as a different drive, however ejecting one would eject all the partitions of the same device as well, and it is perfectly normal)

Comment: @arielnmz If I eject one drive, the other one does not automatically eject, and I can still open it in finder

Comment: I don't know much about macs but maybe it's just unmounting it. Does a partitioning tool (`gparted` or similar) list it as separate drives?